# Drag and drop an image in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im making a drag and drop uploader, here's my drag and drop code:

```
var doc = document.documentElement;
    doc.ondragover = function () {  return false; };
    doc.ondragend = function () {  return false; };
    doc.ondrop = function (event) {
      event.preventDefault && event.preventDefault();

      // now do something with:
      var files = event.dataTransfer.files;

      return false;
    };
```

The problem is, when I drag and drop an image, it loads in a new page. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the html ? And why did you tagged `jquery` if you don't use it ? Would you accept an answer with `jquery` code ?

Comment: Tagged jquery as stack overflow recommended the tag

Comment: Please remove this tag if you are not using the **[jquery](http://jquery.com/)** api.

Comment: Is `now do something with` your exact code? Is that all your code?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling event.preventDefault() twice.  Change one of those to be event.stopPropagation();